# How do I edit the style of bootstrap navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to edit the style of my bootstrap navigation bar. However, I am unable to edit color and remove borders, for example. I would like to just change the color to white and the border color to white as well I have included the code below. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}


.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.navbar-nav > li.navbar-left {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 90%;
  width: auto;
}

.banner {
 width: 100%;
 /*background-color: #c3d7df;*/
}

.banner-inner {
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title> My Website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://jh.com"><img class= "logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="index.html">TRAVEL</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> INSPIRATION</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li> <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    
    
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
 </header>
<!---End Header-->
 <section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-inner">
   <img class="banner" src="img/background.png">
  </div>
 </section>
<!---End Banner-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't create CSS with same name. Create some new set of classes and add in bootstrap navbar.

Comment: Use !important in css properties if you have use the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your css is being overwritten by the default bootstrap css.

You need to make only one change. Use `.navbar.navbar-default` instead of just `.navbar-default` everywhere, this will give your css preference over the default css.

Here's a good article on css specificity :  https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

```css
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffd4d4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border:none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #292929;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffd4d4;
}


.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li.navbar-left {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 90%;
  width: auto;
}

.banner {
 width: 100%;
 /*background-color: #c3d7df;*/
}

.banner-inner {
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
  .container.navbar-container {
     width:100%;
     padding:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title> My Website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="container navbar-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://jh.com"><img class= "logo" src="http://images.financialexpress.com/2015/12/Lead-image.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="navbar-left"><a href="index.html">TRAVEL</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> INSPIRATION</a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
    <li class="navbar-left"><a href="#"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li> <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://www.pinterest.com"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <li> <a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    
    
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
 </header>
<!---End Header-->
 <section class="banner">
  <div class="banner-inner">
   <img class="banner" src="img/background.png">
  </div>
 </section>
<!---End Banner-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133138/discussion-on-answer-by-kittycat-how-do-i-edit-the-style-of-bootstrap-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this Bootstrap Navbar Generator
http://bootstrap3-menu.codedorigin.com/
http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-navbar-online-generator.php